# Sharepoint Provider-Hosted Add-in on Sharepoint 2013 On Premises VM issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to install a Sharepoint Provider-Hosted Add-in (low trust authorization model) on a Sharepoint 2013 on premises environment (Sharepoint 2013 Team Site). The environment is a VM setup and I run it using VMware Player (with a working internet connection). The remote web component of the add-in itself is hosted on Azure, and the add-in works perfectly on Sharepoint Online. The issue I'm having when trying to install it on premises is this:

The add-in contains an event-receiver that creates the infrastructure required by the add-in on the host web (fields, lists and libraries). At first, the Sharepoint context was null and I found out that I had to configure Sharepoint to use an Office 365 environment to authorize provider-hosted add-ins (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-an-office-365-sharepoint-site-to-authorize-provider-hosted-add-ins-on-an-on). This solved the context issue; while debugging, I see that the context is no longer null, and the context also contains the correct host web where I installed the add-in, but it fails at the first context.ExecuteQuery() line with the exception message: "The remote name could not be resolved: 'sp2013dc'". The URL of the site where I'm trying to install the add-in is http://sp2013dc/sites/TeamSiteTest/.

This is the first time I try to install a provider hosted add-in on an on-premises environment. I feel like this is an issue with the way Sharepoint 2013 is configured (Access Mappings, DNS), or maybe with the VM, but I was not able to track it down. Any help would be much appreciated.